# Adobe Flash Player Issue In Chromium In Ubuntu

Tags: flash, chromium

> Playing Youtube videos in chromium I got the following issue

[image]

> Flash play is already installed on the system. How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this issue, use Pepper Flash Player, a safer and more stable version of Flash Player from Google.

Just run the following commands in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

[For More Detail : Source](http://itsfoss.com/fix-flash-player-issue-chromium-in-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: You ask, You answer :P. I guess there needs to be "How To" in addition to "Questions" ! :D